# smbd processes in uninterruptable sleep

Tags: samba, freebsd, zfs, file-sharing, samba4

I have fileserver running FreeBSD 10.1. The server's storage consists of two HDDs in a mirrored ZFS pool.

This server is running Samba 4.1, as domain member. The domain controller is running on another server (Windows Server 2012). I use winbind for AD integration.

The problem is that from time to time (quite often actually) smbd locks up. From a client's perspective, the Samba share is unresponsive.

What is really weird, is that in such an occasion, the offending smbd processes are caught up in a D-state: uninterruptible sleep. I don't understand what could cause this. I don't use NFS mounts on this server and all Samba shares are located on the local ZFS pool.

This problem is especially annoying because I can't fix it by restarting Samba: the frozen smbd processes don't respond to SIGKILL. The only workaround is rebooting.

Here is some `ps aux` information that could help:

```
root            628   0.0  0.7 295348 22688  -  Is   10:50AM   0:05.09 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
root            641   0.0  0.7 295856 22832  -  I    10:50AM   0:01.66 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
p#########    812   0.0  0.9 326684 27132  -  I    11:04AM   0:03.33 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c#########  839   0.0  0.9 329220 27064  -  D    11:07AM   0:07.86 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c#########  939   0.0  0.8 324996 26208  -  I    11:37AM   0:01.22 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c#########  946   0.0  0.9 324988 26504  -  I    11:40AM   0:02.12 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c######### 1077   0.0  0.8 325016 26232  -  I    11:46AM   0:02.00 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c######### 1084   0.0  0.8 325640 26268  -  I    11:49AM   0:01.17 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c######### 1107   0.0  0.9 326200 26864  -  I    11:55AM   0:01.73 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c######### 1141   0.0  0.9 325960 26964  -  I    12:02PM   0:02.20 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c######### 1167   0.0  0.9 326004 26608  -  I    12:08PM   0:01.14 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c######### 1188   0.0  0.9 326192 27044  -  I    12:11PM   0:01.03 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c######### 1195   0.0  0.9 326240 27080  -  I    12:15PM   0:01.15 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c######### 1209   0.0  0.9 326256 26948  -  I    12:20PM   0:01.62 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c######### 1250   0.0  0.8 322384 25768  -  D    12:25PM   0:00.39 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
c######### 1257   0.0  0.8 322384 25908  -  I    12:29PM   0:00.68 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
p#########   1773   0.0  0.8 322752 26004  -  I     2:57PM   0:00.45 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
p#########   1805   0.0  0.8 322752 25188  -  I     3:02PM   0:00.33 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
p#########   1809   0.0  0.8 322752 26040  -  I     3:04PM   0:00.74 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
p#########   1819   0.0  0.8 326980 26276  -  I     3:06PM   0:00.47 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
p#########   1825   0.0  0.8 322752 25952  -  I     3:08PM   0:00.72 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
root           2134   0.0  0.9 323208 26608  -  I     4:58PM   0:02.00 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
root           2160   0.0  0.8 322684 24588  -  I     5:06PM   0:00.78 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
root           2236   0.0  0.9 332140 28256  -  I     5:34PM   0:06.50 /usr/local/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile=/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
```

As can be seen, there are two smbd processes in the D-state. Further examination using procstat:

```
# procstat -t 1250
PID    TID COMM             TDNAME           CPU  PRI STATE   WCHAN
1250 100817 smbd             -                  0  120 sleep   zfs

# procstat -k 1250
PID    TID COMM             TDNAME           KSTACK
1250 100817 smbd             -                mi_switch sleepq_wait sleeplk __lockmgr_args vop_stdlock VOP_LOCK1_APV _vn_lock vacl_get_acl sys___acl_get_file amd64_syscall Xfast_syscall


# procstat -t 839
PID    TID COMM             TDNAME           CPU  PRI STATE   WCHAN
839 100819 smbd             -                  1  120 sleep   filedesc
839 100820 smbd             -                  0  120 sleep   zfs# 

# procstat -k 839
PID    TID COMM             TDNAME           KSTACK
839 100819 smbd             -                mi_switch sleepq_wait _sx_slock_hard namei vn_open_cred zfs_getextattr VOP_GETEXTATTR_APV extattr_get_vp sys_extattr_get_file amd64_syscall Xfast_syscall
839 100820 smbd             -                mi_switch sleepq_wait sleeplk __lockmgr_args vop_stdlock VOP_LOCK1_APV _vn_lock knlist_remove_kq filt_vfsdetach knote_fdclose closefp amd64_syscall Xfast_syscall
```

`procstat -f 839` hangs indefinitely...

I don't know what to draw from this. I'm pretty sure my ZFS pool is clean since I recently scrubbed it:

```
scan: scrub repaired 0 in 3h10m with 0 errors on Fri Apr 17 13:36:50 2015
```

Both HDDs are in good health. Maybe some filesystem-level corruption that a scrub can't detect/fix? Is there a way in which I can see on what files smbd is freezing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar configuration with an AD joined server sharing from zfs, and have experienced the 'sleep' issue in FreeBSD 10.1 and 11.0, and several versions of Samba 3 and 4. I began to notice the lockup would occur mainly on changes to existing files, and not creation or deletion. After running very high samba debug levels, and catching a couple of processes just as they turned zombie, I found something that lead me to look at a problem in inotify.
Adding this to samba config has ended a year and a half of problems for me. "kernel change notify = no"

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I just applied the fix/workaround, I hope it works. I'll try to remember to report back if it worked or not!

Comment: It's been over 12 days without problems now. I think I can confidently say your workaround is working! Thanks!